# Dataframe to Time Series when minutes are repeated

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning

I'm working with clinical data and want to make predictions of patients' waiting time at every minute, and the data (simplified) looks something like this:

```
Time(minutes)    PatientSerial       RemainingTime(minutes)
420              1                      5
420              2                      10
420              3                      8
421              1                      4
421              2                      9
421              3                      7
```

Where 420 is the number of minutes since midnight (420 = 7:00am), where my output is RemainingTime (historical data). In general, the machine learning algorithm should generate waiting time of every patient in each minute, given that the input is clinical data that is generated every minute. But I'm confused as to how to convert this dataframe into Time Series when the same minutes are repeated?

Comment: Couldn't converting the value to seconds and add it to today's zero-hour timestamp, then adding that timestamp to a Time Series help? It is, after all, the meaning of the value you use, right?

Comment: Could you please add a theoretical result. Your question leaves too many end-solution options open. Its also not clear if you have code written to handle this (clarify in your question).

Comment: @BoboDarph Yea but it would still generate multiple same timestamps, which I don't think is allowed for Time Series

Comment: @ZE007 What do you mean by a theoretical result? I only managed to clean up the data but I haven't written down any solution yet. I'm trying to figure out how to start

Comment: my reply in answer... due to assumed table result view.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity: This is not an answer but asking how the result should look like (not able to show the view in comment underneath question). This may help to get a better understanding how this question should be solved. **Edit1: Coded answer is below**.

@Ted:

I would like to know if the result what you try to get is as in the following table:

```
Time (min)   MeanWait (min, single default patient)

...          ...
420          5.2
421          4.9
422          4.3
423          4.2
...
...
820          11.39
821          11.41
822          11.41
823          11.09
824          10.7
825          10.69
...          ...
```

Should the end-result be viewed in PDF using `Matplotlib` or in program GUI on screen? If so modify your question to include that.

**EDIT 1:**

Based on the comments I've made below script that does the core job "calculating" mean patient-waitingtime per unit daytime (minutes). Inline there are comments what happens where. As I reckon you can implement filedata loading and output writing yourself  I did not add that as for the matplotlib. There are many examples [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html) and around the web that suffice.

```
import datetime

# The day timescale is from 0 to 1440 minutes and then resets for day 2.
# The input-textfile can have 24h (0-1440) or continues (e.g. 0-4320 == 3 days) timescaling for x-axis.

# Testset for dataprocessing (day 1 and day2 data)
datas = ['Time(minutes)       RemainingTime(minutes)', 
        '420              :                      5',
        '420              :                      10',
        '420              :                      8',
        '421              :                      4',
        '421              :                      9',
        '421              :                      7',
        '830              :                      8',
        '830              :                      4',
        '340              :                      3',
        '340              :                      5',
        '340              :                      4',
        '351              :                      10',
        '351              :                      7',
        '420              :                      9',
        '420              :                      7',]

def sort_data(scr):

    raw_data            = {}
    day_minute_counter  = 0
    current_list        = []
    day_in_minutes      = (24 * 60)
    elapsed_days_min    = 0           # during processing this holds value in minutes
    processed_days      = 1
    data_from_exception = {}
    count_exceptions    = 0

    for row in scr:
        print row

        try:
            # the following steps take ito account that lapsed time is linear for a single day.
            # each row is being searched for ":" which identifies teh row as having integers or floats.
            x_value, y_value = row.split(":")

#            print 'xy_values : %s, %s' % (x_value, y_value)

            # clipping trailing whitespaces from both ends.
            x_value = x_value.strip(' ')
            y_value = y_value.strip(' ')

            # string > integer conversion
            x_val = int(x_value)
            y_val = int(y_value)

            # set each x-axis timepoint only once.
            if day_minute_counter == 0:
                print 'Start', day_minute_counter, x_val

                day_minute_counter = x_val

            # zipping: append all y-axis datapoint that belong to single x-axispoint
            if day_minute_counter == x_val:
                print 'Append', day_minute_counter, x_val
                current_list.append(y_val)

            # add x,y-axis data to the datalist
            if day_minute_counter < x_val:

                print 'Done', day_minute_counter, x_val, current_list

                raw_data[(day_minute_counter + elapsed_days_min)] = current_list

                day_minute_counter = x_val

                # new list for the next point in the "day_minute_counter".
                current_list      = []  
                current_list.append(y_val)

            # correct x-axis "next-day" time difference.
            if day_minute_counter > x_val:

                processed_days += 1

                print 'Next Day Marker', day_minute_counter, x_val, current_list

                raw_data[(day_minute_counter+ elapsed_days_min)] = current_list

                elapsed_days_min += day_in_minutes
                # reset day_minute_counter because a day has elapsed.
                day_minute_counter = 0
                print 'elapsed_day in minutes : ', elapsed_days_min

        except ValueError:
            #get axis information
            count_exceptions += 1
            data_from_exception[count_exceptions] = row
#            print 'Graph info or "none integer" information collected:\n\n%s > %s\n' % (count_exceptions, row)

    # End of datablock : add the last x,y datapoints without known what EOF marker is being used.
    raw_data[day_minute_counter] = current_list

    print '\nRaw Data   : %s\nOther info : %s\n ' % (raw_data, data_from_exception)

    return (raw_data, processed_days, data_from_exception)

def calc_mean(scr):

    days = scr[1]
    minutes = (days * 24 * 60)
    missing_datapoints = []
    result = []
    print 'Dataset spans a total of "%s" minutes.\n' % minutes

    data = scr[0]

    for x_datapoint in range(1, minutes):

        meanwait  = 0.0
        totalwait = 0

        try:
            # process data from sorte_data.

#            print 'datapoint', x_datapoint  # shows only the absent datapoints on x-axis.
            dataset   = data[x_datapoint]
#            print 'datapoint', x_datapoint  # shows only the available datapoints on x-axis.

            total_values = len(dataset)
            for value in dataset:
                totalwait += value

            meanwait = float(totalwait) / float(total_values)

            x = x_datapoint
            y = meanwait

            result.append((x, y))

            print 'Patient meanwaiting time per Timepoint %s : %.03f' % (x_datapoint, meanwait)

        except Exception:
            missing_datapoints.append(x_datapoint)
#            print 'Patient meainwaiting time "%s" is not available.' % x_datapoint

    return result

def main():

    # open file code here and use readlines to import data to "datas"
    #
    # datas = ...

    ct = str(datetime.datetime.now())[0:23]

    print '%s --> Collecting patient waittime data from Time Series.\n' % ct

    sorted_data = sort_data(datas)   # used template date from this script.

    print 'Processing data to obtain main values'

    the_result = calc_mean(sorted_data)

    print '\nProcessing Finished. Here is the result :\n\n%s' % the_result

    # create new file and store result or keep processing to PDF in matplotlib

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Comment: I think the result you are showing is something that is going to be displayed to individual patient. So yes. The end result should be viewed in PDF using Matplotlib

Comment: Will your data-input-file be a plain text file (e.g. 'txt") with data separated by e.g. comma, tab, ":" or "-"?

Comment: colon ":". Thanks for the help

Comment: Pasted code at EDIT1 should when ran, printed and shown accelerate your patients knowledge in understanding when **"to break a leg"** ;-)

Comment: Okay, I was kind of confused by your code and now see what you're trying to do. Not quite what I was looking for, but really appreciate your effort. I'm not supposed to take the mean of their wait times per unit daytime. Note that in my example, the reason why the time stamps are repeated is because of distinct patient serial number (which uniquely identifies patient). It indicates multiple patients are waiting for their appointment. So ideally, I have to display how many more minutes does each patient has to wait at a given time, not the mean of their remaining time.

Comment: ... aha...EDIT1 is then for patient-waitroom statistics ;-) If I get you then each new patient that comes to the desk gets a new pID and arrival timestamp? Thereafter a count-donw per patient, right? If so.. then that's for tomorrow's coffee/lunchbreak ;-)

Comment: Every person has to book an appointment in order to get a treatment. A patient serial number is assigned once the appointment is registered. Note that those time stamps are not arrival time stamps; it just represents current time. Remaining Time column is a new column that I added by keep tracking of the minute they check-in and the minute they start their treatment. Once calculated the waiting time, I inserted that value in Remaining Time column at the minute they check in, and decrement it by one until they get called for their treatment

Comment: For example if I check in at minute 500 and start treatment at 540,  I put 40 at minute 500 in Remaining Time column. Then 39, 38 ,..., 0. And yea I do have a column that displays when a patient checks in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165522/discussion-between-zf007-and-ted).